# CSS Variables are not being applied

Tags: css

I am trying to use CSS variables but something weird is going on.
I declared the variables like this:

```css
:root {
    --primary: '#fff';
    --black: '#1b1f23';
    --gray: '#586069';
    --orange: '#f9826c';
    --logo: '#fff';
    --header: '#24292e';
    --search: 'rgba(255; 255; 255; 0.13)';
}
```

Then I used them like this:

```css
input {
    background: var(--search);
}
```

But for some reason the style is not being applied.
When I hover the mouse over the variable in Chrome Devtools it shows me the correct value, but it doesn't apply.

[image]

I'm pretty lost on how to make it work.

**Edit:**
I'm using React, so this is the render `<input />`

[image]

Comment: Add your HTML please. its hard to help like this. or provide a minimal working example

Comment: Don't placed property value inside quote `--search: 'rgba(255; 255; 255; 0.13)';`

Answer (score 8):

There are a few problems with your code. The variable values don't need to be a string. And `rgba(255; 255; 255; 0.13)` should be separated with commas, not semicolons. So that would be `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13)`. And the style is being applied; you just can't notice the difference because `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13)` is still white. So the correct CSS for `:root` would be this:

```css
:root {
  --primary: #fff;
  --black: #1b1f23;
  --gray: #586069;
  --orange: #f9826c;
  --logo: #fff;
  --header: #24292e;
  --search: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

Example:

```css
:root {
  --primary: #fff;
  --black: #1b1f23;
  --gray: #586069;
  --orange: #f9826c;
  --logo: #fff;
  --header: #24292e;
  --search: rgba(255, 25, 255, 0.5); /* The color is pink so we can actually see it working */
}

input {
  background: var(--search);
}
```

```html
<input placeholder='Enter Username or Repo...'>
```

Comment: Oh I see, I imported these styles from a third part file, didn't even realize the quotes were  the problem and didn't even see the semicolons in the wrong place, thanks! It seems it is working now